# Unable to find executable

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I am completely new to ROS and programming in C++, I am looking for a program to move the turtlebot forward and found a tutorial named sending simple goals to navigation stack. However, I tried the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals) to move the robot forward by 1 meter. I have followed the tutorial in the exact way but unable to execute the program and it shows an error message:

```
asun@asun-Latitude-E6400:~$ rosrun simple_navigation_goals simple_navigation_goals

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named simple_navigation_goals below /home/asun/catkin_ws/src/simple_navigation_goals
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/asun/catkin_ws/src/simple_navigation_goals
[rosrun]   /home/asun/catkin_ws/src/simple_navigation_goals/include/simple_navigation_goals
```

I can see the executable file under this folder:

```
home/asun/catkin_ws/src/simple_navigation_goals/include/simple_navigation_goals
```

Please help me with the solution. I am using ROS-Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS precise.

Also, I am completely new to this. Please help me with any tutorial in C++ or python to move the robot forward or backward in the simulator as well as the turtlebot itself using code but not teleop.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I have built the code using catkin_make and it produced the following result:

```
asun@asun-Latitude-E6400:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws/
asun@asun-Latitude-E6400:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/asun/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/asun/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/asun/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/asun/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/asun/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/asun/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/asun/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/asun/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 5 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials
-- ~~  - geometry_msgs
-- ~~  - agitr
-- ~~  - enclosure_escape
-- ~~  - simple_navigation_goals
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tutorials)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'geometry_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry_msgs)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'agitr'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(agitr)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'enclosure_escape'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(enclosure_escape)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'simple_navigation_goals'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(simple_navigation_goals)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/asun/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/asun/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 16%] Built target listener
[ 16%] [ 16%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target hello
[ 33%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] [ 33%] Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target move_base_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[ 33%] [ 33%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 33%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 50%] Built target talker
[ 83%] [ 83%] Built target subpose
Built target pubvel
[100%] Built target simple_navigation_goals
```

Then i have executed the program using command
rosrun simple_navigation_goals simple_navigation_goals
but this time it shows a new error which doesnt make sense, as i have created a package myself as per the tutorial.

```
asun@asun-Latitude-E6400:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun simple_navigation_goals simple_navigation_goals
[rospack] Error: stack/package simple_navigation_goals not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194412/unable-to-find-executable/) by [Bharath Javvadhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20403/bharath-javvadhi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinCote](https://answers.ros.org/users/20034/martincote/) on 2014-10-15**:
What's your CMakeList.txt look like? Can you confirm where simple_navigation_goals.cpp is located?

You also asked for more tutorials, you can check out our [ROS tutorials](http://support.clearpathrobotics.com) The ROS101: Creating a workspace, package and publisher tutorial seems to suit your needs

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-06**:
I am facing the same issue, have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you missed sourcing your workspace after `catkin_make`:

```
source /home/asun/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

If you have only sourced the setup.bash of the ros distro in /opt/ros/...  your environment will not know where the packages/execs in your workspace are places....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bharath Javvadhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20403/bharath-javvadhi/) on 2014-10-08**:
I have sourced it as per your comments. Now it returns to the previous error and displays that the executable is not found.